# What is wrong with this formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I'm trying to make a formula that converts an ellipse in general form to one in standard. My steps to derive it are as follows:
$$ax^2+bx+cy^2+dx+e=0$$

Move e to the other side...

$$ax^2+bx+cy^2+dx=-e$$

"Complete the square" on both quadratics...

$$a(x+\frac{b}{2a}) + c(y+\frac{d}{2c})=\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{d^2}{4c^2}-e$$

I decided I only needed this much of the formula, as it was obvious that i would just divide the right side by the left to convert to the form
$$\frac{(x^2-h)}{a^2}+\frac{(y^2-k)}{b^2}=1$$

However, when I tested it with the equation $9x^2-54x+4y^2+8y+49 = 0$

I substituted in the variables, and the left side checked out:
$$9(x-3)^2 + 4(y+1)^2$$

However, when I tried to compute the right side, I got a result that neither nine nor four are factors of.
$$\frac{(-54)^2}{4(9)^2} + \frac{(8)^2}{4(4)^2} - 49$$
$$\frac{2916}{324} + \frac{64}{64} - 49$$
$$9 + 1 - 49 = -39$$

As [this Wolfram|Alpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ellipse%209x%5E2%20-%2054x%20%2B%204y%5E2%20%2B%208y%20%3D%20-49%20standard%20form) shows, I should be getting 36 on the left, but I'm getting negative 39. I can't seem to find an error in either the formula or the math.

Comment: I think you completed the square wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a(x^2+\frac{b}{2a}x +\frac{b^2}{4a^2}) + c(y^2+\frac{d}{2c}y + \frac{d^2}{4c^2})=\color{red}{a}\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\color{red}{c}\frac{d^2}{4c^2}-e$$

There are errors when completing the square. <s>First, it appears that you omitted the two red terms on the left hand side.</s> More importantly, the terms you must add to the right hand side are missing the factors $a$ and $c$ respectively. Do you see where they came from?

Comment: Oh whoops, the missing terms in completing the square were because of a typo in the question. The proper equation for that step is  $(x+\frac{b}{2a}) + c(y+\frac{d}{2c})=\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{d^2}{4c^2}-e$. I'll edit the question! The missing a and c factors are the mistake I was making, however! Thanks!

Comment: That's what I figured. I'll "un"-red them :)

Comment: And the x and y terms should be squared.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't complete the square right. Do the following for both $ x, y $,

$$
ax^2 + bx + c + ... = ... \\
a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}) + c + ... = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + ... \\
a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 + c + ... = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + ...
$$

Do that for both x and y.